# REST API for authorising endurance file storage Softlayer

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I want a REST API for authorising File storage(endurance) that I ordered from Softlayer to my VM or BM. Please help me with how can I do that.

Thanks,
Kishore

Answer (score 0):

Here is the API endpoint for that.

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/allowAccessFromHostList

To authorize/allow hosts, please execute:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/[Storage_id]/allowAccessFromHostList

Method: POST

{
  "parameters": [
    [
      {
        "id": 13548553,
        "objectType": "SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

The Above request is used to authorize “Endurance” and “Performance” If you want to authorize “Virtual Guest”,“IpAddress” or “Hardware”, valid values for “objectType” are:

“SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest “,”SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress”, ”SoftLayer_Hardware” respectively.

Comment: Hi Kimmo, does the API you have given work for Endurance File storage also, I thought it is for Endurance Block storage, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks, this worked for endurance file storage also.

Comment: It should those are the same cluster providing both block and file